# Is there a way to create multiple articles in Joomla at one back-end page?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, backend

I tried to google it, but don't get anything useful.
Sometimes creating new articles in Joomla getting slow and boring. I need to fill few fields in different tabs and press "save & new", then repeat it many times. Is there a way to create multiple articles as table, where row is one article? It may be a component for back-end or script or MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out OS Content by JoomlaShack:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/oscontent/

Video demo at https://demoextensions.joomlashack.com/oscontent

Comment: Almost what I need. The only thing missing is attaching tags and specifying individual dates

Answer (score 0):

If this is a once off you could create a CSV with all of your articles and import it directly into the #__content database table if you have access to phpMyAdmin or similar.

The downside to this solution is the data is inserted without using the JTable class. This means that any filtering or dependent fields like 'alias' won't be populated and auto-populated fields like 'created' will also be empty. But it sounds like you want to specify some these fields manually anyway.

A workaround to populate these fields is to do the import and then open each article and save. The JTable class is used on this first save and does some updating for you.

For adding the tags, this is a different table #__contentitem_tag_map. If you've already created all your tags in #__tags you can match the article ids, with the tag ids and insert them into #__contentitem_tag_map.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SP PageBuilder and that allows you to clone pages as many times as you want.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user/developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us to resolve some of our open questions.